# npm install failing with proxy authentication required despite noproxy being set

Tags: npm

I have an issue with `npm install`. I have configured `npm` to use my company's registry and configured the proxy to get external dependencies and set `noproxy` for my company's intranet.

```
noproxy = "*.intra.company.fr"
proxy = "http://user:pass@proxy.intra.company.fr:8080/"
registry = "http://registry.subdomain.intra.company.fr/repository/npm/"
```

However, when I try to install my project, I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code E407
npm ERR! 407 Proxy Authentication Required - GET http://registry.subdomain.intra.company.fr/repository/npm/@babel/types/-/types-7.15.0.tgz
```

I checked, I have no system environment variables set for `HTTP_PROXY`, `PROXY` or `NO_PROXY`.

Edit: npm version is 6.14.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your NPM version ? you should be able to set `noproxy` on a domain wih **NPM 6.4.1+** with a custom registry configured.

```
npm config set noproxy "*.intra.company.fr"
```

But maybe there is an issue with `*`, can you try to set your `noproxy` with your private registry ?

```
noproxy = "registry.subdomain.intra.company.fr"
```

You could also try to manually change your config in `.npmrc`.

By default, the value of `noproxy` is taken from the `no_proxy` environment variable. Try to use it to fix your issue.

```
export no_proxy="intra.company.fr"
```

Comment: I edited the question with the npm version: 6.14.15. npm install works with `noproxy = "registry.subdomain.intra.company.fr"`. I guess the problem was from the wildcard

Comment: I also tried to put `*.subdomain.intra.company.fr` but it doesn't work. I though maybe it didn't handle more than one subdomain. I guess the wildcard is totally broken. Or my system.

Comment: It should be enough to use noproxy with your registry and not the domain, but if you want to keep it as a wildcard, the environment variable NO_PROXY should work `export no_proxy="intra.company.fr"`

Comment: it does work with the environment variable!

Comment: That was my guess, I use something similar with composer, and you can see why it work here: https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx2.8.7/breakout/lynx_help/keystrokes/environments.html (search for NO_PROXY)